# Transforming a disk to a ring

Tags: geometric-transformation

I was reading the beautiful book "New Horizons in Geometry" from Apostol and Mamikon. One of the basic ideas from the book is that geometric transformation from a disk to a ring is area-preserving (see image).

How could I find the non-linear map that transform a disk to a ring? From the book I guess that there is one.

[image: disk to a ring]